# oData - How to dynamically include a relational property for a single result?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, odata

I've noticed that oData will automatically include variables for collections.

How can I make this work the same way for an oData query that returns one item?

For example, if I add "$expand=Customer" to this call.  It will work with out me explicitly doing so in linq (.Include(p => p.Customer)

```
    public IEnumerable<ProjectEntity> Get()
    {
        return _db.Projects;
    }
```

But this code will not automatically include project with the same syntax:

```
public ProjectEntity GetProjectById(int id)
    {
        return _db.Projects.Where(p => p.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is often misunderstood about OData, you need to return an `IQueryable<T>` expression for the `$expand` query option to be dynamically applied to your response object, there is a special wrapper for this [`SingleResult<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnet.odata.singleresult?view=odata-aspnetcore-7.0).

The key is that you do not want to materialize the expression using `.FirstOrDefault()` but we still want the response to be a constrained to a single object in the JSON response instead of an array.

```
[EnableQuery]
public SingleResult<ProjectEntity> GetProjectById(int id)
{
    return SingleResult.Create(_db.Projects.Where(p => p.Id == id));
}
```

---

If you didn't want to use `SingleResult<T>` then a hack would be to pre-emptively load the navigation property by *Including* it in the query.

```
public ProjectEntity GetProjectById(int id)
{
    return _db.Projects.Include(p => p.Customer)
                       .Where(p => p.Id == id)
                       .FirstOrDefault();
}
```